# Events on Master Page event not firing with Validation Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, validation-controls

I have applied some **textboxes in content pages**. I have applied some Validations Controls on it.

What i have done so far is this,

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtE1" runat="server" CssClass="input_type_text" Width="75px"  CausesValidation="false" ValidationGroup="te" >
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqdE1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtE1"
                         ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

I have a Sign Out link on the master Page. I am unable to generate that event.
Any other thing i am missing/required?

Comment: Can you post a little bit more of your code?

Comment: I think that yuo have to definete validation group for your validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have validation errors on the page, the javascript validation prevents the page to postback. If sign out is in the scope of the textbox's form, maybe this is the problem in your case. Can you see if there are validation errors?

Comment: I know the javascript is preventing it from firing. What do you mean that sign out is the scope? Please elaborate

Comment: If it is in the asp.net form may be it cause validation before to postback. Try as Boriss said to create a validation group http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx